# Rails generator `inject_into_file` at the end of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-generate, rails-generators

Is there a way to append something to file using generator's [`inject_into_file`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#inject-into-file)? It has to get a `:before` or `:after` parameter but what should I pass to just append something?

Answer (score 4):

Please use [append_to_file](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Actions#append_to_file-instance_method)

```
append_to_file "file.rb" do 
  "hello"
end
```